# how do I format a python script to run cloud code on Parse?

Tags: python, parse-platform, cloud

Parse's quickstart guide gives this Python code to get started using cloud code:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/functions/hello', json.dumps({
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

This code gives me a syntax error when I run it now matter what I do to it. How do I change the quotes or formatting to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to resolve whatever syntax problem there was:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
jdump = {'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
json_jdumps = json.dumps(jdump)
connection.request('POST', '/1/functions/hello', json_jdumps, headers)
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```